# Google Sheets Scripts Moving input field answers to a blank out put field

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api

I'm still working on a sheet for the Music Studio I work at and I have been stumped again.
I've spent the last few days reading things like

```
1) https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet

2)https://mashe.hawksey.info/2015/03/google-sheets-move-a-row-of-data-to- 
another-sheet-based-on-cell-value/
```

Trying to copy a Cell from an intake form to an output column on a different sheet.

I'm currently using this code I found on StackOverflow I tried to edit to suit my needs.

```html
function NewBand(){ //Triggered by button on "New"
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var target = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  
  var source_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('New');
  var target_sheet = target.getSheetByName('Roster');
  var source_range = source_sheet.getRange('D3');
  var target_range = target_sheet.getRange('C10');
    source_range.copyTo(target_range);
  var last_row = target_sheet.getLastRow();
  target_sheet.insertRowAfter(last_row);
  var target_range = target_sheet.getRange('C'+(last_row+1));

  var source_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('New');
  var target_sheet = target.getSheetByName('Info');
  var source_range = source_sheet.getRange('D5');
  var target_range = target_sheet.getRange('B8');
    source_range.copyTo(target_range);
  var last_row = target_sheet.getLastRow();
  target_sheet.insertRowAfter(last_row);
}
```

Currently, when it runs, it correctly adds data to the correct columns, but

1)it doesn't insert the data into the next cell preserving the previously 
  inserted data.
    -It overwrites the previous entry currently as opposed to moving down a row and creating new data.

2) when I run it, it adds a bunch of blank rows too.

3) if there is an easier way to do this that would also be great!
If someone can get me on the right track or get the first form to output correctly,so i can do the rest I'd be eternally grateful!

If it helps here is a very simple version of my project:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1i192uK-a-ALim7pvL-mkty_1nh_m9aghvmrxmiiRYKs/edit?usp=sharing

I color coded the input forms in the sheet "New" to match my desired outputs on sheets "roster" and "info".

I'd also be more than happy to tip someone a couple of bucks for their time if they have paypal or apple pay

Comment: Even pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: I saw your shared spreadsheet. Can I ask you about the difference between your script in your question and in your shared spreadsheet? And in order to understand correctly what you want to do, can you provide a sample flow you want?

Comment: @Tanaike Hi! Yes absolutely! it is the same code as the one in my sample sheet. in plain English : When Sheet "NEW" is filled out,  The user clicks the "NewBand" Button in the new sheet and all the data in the color-coded column is sent to the color-coded columns in the rest of the sheet Then information in the "input Color-coded column" is erased

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to confirm before modify the script. I'm sorry for my poor English skill. You want to achieve as follows. 1. Put the values to "D3, D5, D7, D9, D11, D13, D14, D15" in the sheet "New". 2. Click the image of "NewBand". 3. You want to add the inputted values of "D3, D7, D9, D11" to the last row of columns C, D, J and Q in the sheet "Roster", respectively. 4. You want to add the inputted values of "D5, D14, D15, D11" to the last row of columns B, C, D and H in the sheet "Info", respectively. Is my understanding for your reply correct?

Comment: @Tanaike     PRECISELY! Your English is fine! probably better than mine and I am a native speaker!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could know that my understanding was correct. I have one more question. About the format of the values in the sheet "New", do you want to also copy the format? Or do you want to copy only the values?

Comment: @Tanaike     Only the values

Comment: Thank you for replying. I posted an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstand what you want to do, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this modification? In this modification, it retrieves the values "D3:D15" and puts each value to the next row of last row of the sheet "Roster" and "Info".

#### Modified script:

```
function NewBand() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetNew = ss.getSheetByName('New');
  var sheetRoster = ss.getSheetByName('Roster');
  var sheetInfo = ss.getSheetByName('Info');
  var values = sheetNew.getRange("D3:D15").getValues();
  var D3, D5, D7, D9, D11, D13, D14, D15;
  [D3, _, D5, _, D7, _, D9, _, D11, _, D13, D14, D15] = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], values);
  sheetRoster.appendRow([,null,D3,D7,null,null,null,null,null,D9,null,null,null,null,null,null,D11]);
  sheetInfo.appendRow([null,D5,D14,D15,null,null,null,D11]);
}
```

#### Note:

- In this script, it supposes that the next row of last row is as follows.

  - There are no values in the columns except for C, D, J and Q in the sheet "Roster"
  - There are no values in the columns except for B, C, D and H in the sheet "Info".

#### References:

- [Array.prototype.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)
- [appendRow(rowContents)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object))

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183968/discussion-on-answer-by-tanaike-google-sheets-scripts-moving-input-field-answers).